# ArcGIS Server Data Source

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase

Is there a way to tell if a map service is using an SDE database as its data source, through either the REST or SOAP APIs?

I'm working with an app that queries a map service, and it is not returning the correct results if the service is based off of shape files or personal geodatabases.

Comment: Do you have admin access to the server, or just user level?

Comment: I think you're out of luck then. Your only hope would be the individual put some metadata you could read http://SERVER:6080/arcgis/rest/services/SERVICENAME/MapServer/info/iteminfo

Comment: @KHibma - User level ideally, but if it can only be done with admin access, that would definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have admin access (that is access to the admin REST endpoint, you can get information about the workspace from the manifest).
For example:

http://SERVER:6080/arcgis/admin/services/SERVICENAME.MapServer/iteminfo/manifest/manifest.json?f=pjson

Yields:

> "databases": [{
>       "byReference": false,
>       "onServerWorkspaceFactoryProgID": "**esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory**",
>       "onServerConnectionString": "ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD=123;SERVER=DATABASENAME;INSTANCE=sde:sqlserver:ne2k864;DBCLIENT=sqlserver;DB_CONNECTION_PROPERTIES=DATABASENAME;DATABASE=kevin;USER=sde;VERSION=sde.DEFAULT;AUTHENTICATION_MODE=DBMS",
>       "onPremiseConnectionString": "DATABASE=C:\Users\username\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb",
>       **"onServerName": "sde.DEFAULT (DATABASE)",**
>       "onPremisePath": "",
>       "datasets": [{"onServerName": "layerName"}]   }],